# Division of Parasha into seven Aliyos

Tags: torah-reading, pentateuch-chumash

Who is the author of the marks dividing Parashios  into seven aliyos found today in almost all chumashim?

Notes: The halacha (Mishna in Megillah 21a, Shulchan Aruch OC 135) prescribes that 7 people should be called up to read from the Torah on Shabbos. Today, almost all chumashim have marks to show where each aliyah begins and ends (i.e. sheini, shloshi etc). While there are slight differences between chumashim (such as Koren and Artscroll), there is general uniformity among the chumashim printed in the past few centuries. I understand there are exceptions (such as the Yemenite Taj) that follow a different order.